# Can typescript handle dynamic return type NOT based on a function param?

Tags: typescript

I know how to handle dynamic type checking using a param type but I'm stuck with this one. It may be not possible, but I can't think straight anymore so any help is welcome !

Given the code:

```
class DefaultClass {
    defaultProp: number;
    constructor(num: number) {
        this.defaultProp = num;
    }
}

class MyClass extends DefaultClass {
    myProp ?: string;
    constructor(num: number, str ?: string) {
        super(num);
        this.myProp = str || "default value";
    }
    myMethod(str: string): string[] {
        return [str];
    }
}

interface Config {
    class: typeof DefaultClass;
}

const config: Config = {
    class: DefaultClass
}

function initConfig(classType: typeof DefaultClass) {
    config.class = classType;
}

// we don't care for the param type, it's irrelevant here
function myFunction(param: any): InstanceType<typeof config.class> {
    // does something based on which class is used in config
    // returns a DefaultClass or MyClass instance based on the current config
    return new config.class(1);
}

initConfig(MyClass);
const myInstance: MyClass = myFunction("something");
// ERR !: Property 'myMethod' is missing in type 'DefaultClass'
// but required in type 'MyClass'.
```

As you can guess the static type checking can't dynamically change the return type based on changes done on the `config` object as it is not "known" before the run. Yet I would like to find a way (if any) to do it.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code to make it a [mcve] where the only issues present are the ones you are asking about.  Right now that code is [riddled with errors](https://tsplay.dev/jwgqBm) so it makes it much harder for anyone to use it to answer your question.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Sorry about that, was in a rush, my fault. Code is fixed and more accurate regarding the error. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't really handle type mutation all that well; at best it does type *narrowing*, and even then it doesn't propagate such narrowing across function boundaries so there's no way narrowing `config` will have any affect on the return type of `myFunction()`.  If you care about types enough to deal with this in TS I'd recommend a significant refactoring to make the types of things immutable like [this](https://tsplay.dev/OwEqOw).  If that's acceptable I could write up an answer.  Otherwise I think the answer is just "no".

Comment: @jcalz I really liked the way you did it and I messed with my code a bit to test the pattern, but the major drawback is indeed function boundaries and mutation. As soon as I try to set `DefaultClass` as ... a default class (like a wrapping _init_ function), everything goes back to the initial issue. And if I try to set the default in the `Impl` class, I got the `Type 'typeof DefaultClass' is not assignable to type 'T' [...]` error. I guess there is no way to set a default value in this case. Thanks for your time !

Comment: You can do it with type assertions like [this](https://tsplay.dev/YmpJgw) although it's not technically type safe (someone *could* write `new Impl<MyClass>()`, but in practice they won't).  Do you want me to write any of this up as an answer?

Comment: I'll be glad if you do. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problems with supporting what you're doing directly in TypeScript is that it requires:

- the *type* of variables to mutate over time, and
- these effects need to be visible *across function boundaries*.

---

**No arbitrary type mutation**

TypeScript doesn't support for *arbitrarily* changing the type of an expression or variable. There's no way to do something like `let foo = {a: "hello"}; foo = {b: 123};` and have the compiler change the apparent type of `foo` from `{a: string}` to `{b: number}`. You can annotate the type of `foo` like `let foo: {a?: string; b?: number}`, but then the compiler won't notice that anything has changed from one assignment to the next.

All it *does* have is [*narrowing* via control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).  So if you have a value of some known type, it's possible via assignments or other tools like [user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) or [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) to make a variable's apparent type more specific.  And so you could conceivably make the compiler notice that `config` has been narrowed from type `{class: typeof Defaultclass}` to `{class: typeof MyClass}`.  But:

**No type narrowing effects across function boundaries**

It doesn't help you because you want changes to the type of `config` to be visible to callers of `myFunction()`.  And this cannot happen because `myFunction()` will only see changes in the type of `config` that occur directly inside the body of `myFunction()`.  Control flow narrowing does not persist across function boundaries, because it would be impossible to implement a general solution that both works and does not seriously degrade compiler performance.  There is a GitHub issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998), that talks about the problems with trying to deal with narrowing effects when functions are called.

So you're kind of stuck.

---

Instead of doing it this way, my recommendation is: if you want TypeScript to help you, do things it understands.  The best thing to do with a variable is to just keep it the same type for its entire lifetime.  The implication for your code is to never modify `config` by calling `initConfig()`, and instead use the parameters to `initConfig` to *create* `myFunction()` instead.  This will have to be packaged as a sort of factory that spits out an implementation. We can use `class` for that:

```
class Impl<T extends typeof DefaultClass = typeof DefaultClass> {
    class: T
    constructor(classType: T = DefaultClass as T) {
        this.class = classType;
    }
    myFunction(param: any) {
        return new this.class(1) as InstanceType<T>;
    }
}

const CurImpl = new Impl(MyClass);
const myInstance: MyClass = CurImpl.myFunction("something");

const DifferentImpl = new Impl();
const differentInstance: DefaultClass = DifferentImpl.myFunction("else");
```

Here `CurImpl` knows about `MyClass` because it is an instance of `Impl<typeof MyClass>`, and its type never changes.  If you want to use a different class constructor you have to make a new instance of `Impl<T>` for some `T`.

---

In the above, as an aside, I used a [generic parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) so that if `T` can't be inferred it will use `typeof DefaultClass`.  And if you don't pass in a `classType` parameter, the compiler will use `DefaultClass`. This is technically not type safe, because the compiler can't be sure that `T` will actually be `typeof DefaultClass` if you don't pass in the parameter.  Someone could call `new Impl<typeof MyClass>()` and break things.  Assuming that nobody would do such a thing, I used a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler that if `classType` is not passed in, then the `DefaultClass` value is assignable to type `T`.  There might be more type-safe ways to do this (possibly without a `class`) but I don't want to go too far afield of the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiCmAzMBXEAXAwuK0DeAUNMdACZKoYAKATgPYAOAXNAHYoC2ARvDQNxESwOqwjoaKYOjo0AFOw4sFPGgEp8gkiXQALAJYQAdOWRp0tRtAC8bTgK0BfAk4KhIMALIBPbO+jwAD3R4VlIYBFMMX1xCLQ4vCwYAfhYxGj1WAHN7IRE0yWk5BSVOFQAaaDSUyvEMzPVYrRIIFAZeeU5VHKboXQNDeMTrGppoAB8x6AAiE0p0aAA3MBAUeCnu6Cc4rw94XTpSWTTU2qzVE-SsgG0AXQ0e4ho9lBpWaCu0m42nFzdcAEkOAwQAAeAAq-iCITCvS8bToiDgFDM0RgNnQcPgCKRkSwOAgAD57kJ8SwwZpoMJROICjJZH8IGDMWThhE5qjoJBoGCGhStH0jAzhgymW1vhT4gAxFCsKR6ESyBhgGhgRSc1heXkPaBPdAvN6seAAd16+kF+NkAEZ1Fz-tSwLL4KL4OCCeKnFSxNBMC9AcDhoaTX6QLJvKiuq48vN4naxA7gPAWGH8cMfTRgwMvNLZeh5axZFMIHQOHt9FkphHI9S4HpEIheCF0MGA8boMHZBHPfNSLX609WE37Y6WGyUSmbLBew2BxmpTK5QqpvAQBA1pWgA)

Comment: With some experimentation, I realized I will not be able to fully use it on my project, but you answer helped me a lot to understand Typescript in depth. Thank you !